# Making maps of XML response node data in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to store XML response node values in a map but it's REALLY complicated. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SearchRS>
    <SearchStatus>SUCCESS</SearchStatus>
    <Itinerary>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
        <Ticket>111.11</Ticket>
        <Taxes>1.11</Taxes>
    </Itinerary>
    <Itinerary>
        <Name>Bob</Name>
        <Ticket>222.22</Ticket>
        <Taxes>2.22</Taxes>
    </Itinerary>
    <Itinerary>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
        <Ticket>333.33</Ticket>
        <Taxes>3.33</Taxes>
        </Itinerary>
    <Itinerary>
    <Itinerary>
        <Name>Bob</Name>
        <Ticket>444.44</Ticket>
        <Taxes>4.44</Taxes>
    </Itinerary>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
        <Ticket>0.0</Ticket>
        <Taxes>0.0</Taxes>
    </Itinerary>
</SearchRS>
```

I need to compute the average ticket+taxes for each name.

**Note: Any value of 0.0 should be excluded from the average.**

I want to create a map that will contain the following:

```
[ name : average of ticket+taxes value]
```

What I tried, this will find the minium value for each, doc.Itinerary holds the XML response.

```
  def minByName = doc.Itinerary
            .inject([:].withDefault { [] }) { map, it ->
       map[it.Name.text()] << it
       map
  }
  .collectEntries { profile, nodes ->
       [profile, nodes.min { it.Ticket.text() as Double }]
  }

  def nameList = []
    minByName.each { profile, minimum ->
        Map nameMap = [:]
        nameMap.name = profile
        nameMap.ticket = minimum.Ticket.toString()
        nameMap.taxes = minimum?.Taxes
        nameList << nameMap
  }
 log.info("Cheapest ticket and tax per name: " + nameList)
```

Which would result in a set of data per name:

```
[[name:Joe, ticket:111.11, taxes:1.11], [name:Bob, etc...]]
```

Instead of minimum I want the values in the map to be the average of, for example, all of Joe's ticket+taxes.

Which would look like this:

```
[[name:Joe, averageCost:224.44], [name:Bob, averageCost...]]
```

**111.11+1.11 = 112.22, 333.33+3.33 = 336.66. 112.22+336.66 = 448.88. 448.88/2 = 224.44**

I'm really stuck on this one, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think `Itinerary` node misplaced in your xml. If it is strict like i said update the question (because the nodes like `name` is common; better you keep it in particular position) or you are getting it in random way, check with my answer.

Comment: Have got chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this what you are after (explained in-line comment):

```
//pass xmlString to below
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
def map = [:]
//Find unique names, then  respective Iteneraries, then collect ticket & taxes, convert to Double, eliminate 0 values, sum and average, put into map
xml.'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'Name'}.unique().each { name -> 
   map[name] = xml.'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'Itinerary' && name == it.Name.text() }.collect { Double.parseDouble(it.Ticket.text()) + Double.parseDouble(it.Taxes.text())}.findAll {it}.with { sum() / size() }
}
println map
```

Please find the quick <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/7hrZBR)</kbd>

**EDIT:** Addressing the OP's comment.

Change `sum()` to `sum().round(2)`

Comment: This works great but I have one question? How would I round off the floating point number? Not sure where to stick the .round(2)...

Comment: Sorry I did not get. Can you clarify the same with an example data? Appreciate an up vote for the helpful answers.

Comment: With that code I get a map of the right values but need to round off after the decimal point. For example [Bob:21.549999999999997, Joe:10.67285714285714, Tom:10.40666666666667]  It would better to round it off to, for example 21.54, 10.67 and 10.40 but I'm not sure where to place the .round(2)

Comment: You could do that. By the way, that was not in the original question, so I can't imagine.

Comment: @PeterCook, please check the edit part for your comment. Also find the script [here](https://ideone.com/lI5BgS).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right,

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File ('/tmp/stack.xml'))

List <String> names = root.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == "Name"}.collect{it}

List <Map> totalresult = []

names.unique().each{name ->

    Map result = [:]

    result["name"] = name

    List<Float> tickets = root.'**'.findAll{ it.Name == name && it.Ticket.toFloat() > 0.0}.collect { it.Ticket.toFloat() + it.Taxes.toFloat() }

    result ["total"] = tickets.sum()

    result ["occurances"]= tickets.size()

    result ["avgCosts"] = result.total/result.occurances

    totalresult.add(result)

}

println totalresult
```

Update 1 : code corrected as per requirement.